# Reduce remote desktop first time login delays on windows XP embedded

Tags: remote-desktop, delay, windows-xp-embedded

For some reason, when I remote desktop into a windows xp embedded machine it always takes ages to connect. After the first connection, it connects right away.

Is there a way to stop this delay?

**Edit** - Update..

I tried runnnig a before and after on the services running on the machine and it looks like after the remote desktop has had it's pause and loaded, the following two processes appear:

```
csrss.exe
winlogon.exe
```

Presumably these are the two things which are taking a while to fire up? Which begs the question; how can I get them to start up when the machine starts?

**Edit2** - Multiple log-ons..

If one user tries to connect and suffers the 20-30 second delay, subsequent users don't see the same delay which supports the theory that there's something loading up once on the host system.

Comment: Any chance that your DNS is going really slowly?

Comment: I'm connecting to an IP address so seems unlikely..

Comment: Sounds like some kind of timeout.

Could it be a certificate issue?

Comment: How would I check?

Answer (score 1):

Check in the Services applet if the Startup type of the service "Terminal Services" 
is set to Automatic. If it is set to Manual then change it to Automatic.

In explanation, I think that in Windows XP Embedded this service is by default configured
to start on demand, started by winlogon.exe after a delay (about 1 minute I think).
It is impossible to change this delay, but one can change
the startup type to Automatic, which will then make Remote Desktop
come up faster, but slightly slow down the overall boot time.

If for some reason you don't have access to the Services applet,
the same manipulation can be done via regedit :

Open the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\TermService` and
change the value of the `Start` item from "3" to "2" and reboot.

**Another hypothesis** : The logged user is being prompted for confirmation.

The delay you are experiencing is then the time given to the logged user to confirm
or cancel the automatic logoff of his session.

This can be changed in the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) under:
Administrative Templates / Windows components / Terminal Services.

Double-click **Set rules of remote control of remote desktop services**
and choose the Option of **Full control without user's permission**
for the logged user not to be prompted for confirmation.
I suggest also to reboot.

If you don't have that policy in XPE, it is also found in the registry at:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services`
as a DWORD key named `Shadow`, where value 2 means "Full Control without user's permission".

Comment: I just tried that and it made no difference. I still have an ~20-30second delay.

Comment: Long time since I last used XP. Are you using vpn? Is there something in the Event log? What operating system on the machine connecting to XP?

Comment: No VPN; standard Ethernet connection via a single D-Link switch (connecting direct makes no difference). I was connecting from a Windows 7 machine, but I get the same behaviour when connecting from a Windows XP machine.

Comment: When the remote desktop is first initiated, is there already a logged-in session on the XP?

Comment: Correct; there is a user automatically logged on as soon as the machine starts.

Comment: I added another hypothesis above.

Comment: It's the same user that's currently logged on that's being logged into if that makes a difference? I don't appear to have Terminal Services listed in the group policies... ?

Comment: Same user doesn't mean same session. I added more info on how to do the same using regedit.

Comment: Tried the 'Shadow' registry option and rebooted but that doesn't appear to have made a measurable difference either - still ~20 seconds to log in :-/

Comment: You can test my 2nd hypothesis by disabling temporarily the automatic logon after boot to see if this improves the speed. If it does, then there might be more research that can be done. But it's always possible that this simply doesn't work on the stripped-down embedded version.

Comment: I changed `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon` to `0` and then tried to log in and it took ~25 seconds to get in so still no improvement there.

Comment: Was this without an existing logged-in session? I would like the RDP login to be the very first login after the boot.

Comment: Yes, I did as you suggested; the machine booted to the log-in prompt then I remote-desktop'd in to log in ...and it made no difference.

Comment: I am starting to think the problem is the stripped-down terminal server in XPE. You could simply replace it using the material [found here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/enable-multiple-concurrent-remote-desktop-connections-or-sessions-in-windows-xp/). However, you do this wild idea at your own risk as this can render the device unbootable. Here is [another link](http://fawzi.wordpress.com/2008/02/09/enabling-multiple-remote-desktop-sessions-in-windows-xp/) found [by googling](https://www.google.fr/search?q=xp+multiple+remote+desktop+sessions&btnG=Search&hl=en-FR&biw=&bih=).

Comment: We really don't want multiple sessions as our core software isn't a service.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting multiple sessions, and your core software not being a service is unrelated. I was suggesting the shameful hack of replacing your XPE terminal server by a version of the non-embedded XP terminal server. I don't blame you if you choose not to, as there is a good chance that this will cause problems, maybe even render the device unbootable, beside the unclear legalities of this all. Just exasperated with none of the suggested solutions working on XPE.

Comment: If you read the article though, those are just the original terminal service .dll's hacked to allow multiple sessions? I'm not loading hacked .dll's onto a production system though; I'd rather live with the pause!

Comment: These are original dlls dating to a release before Microsoft's Marketing decided to place artificial limitations on sessions in XP. But you are absolutely right : one shouldn't hack a production system. My conclusion: None of the known remedies work for you, so that I at least don't have any more ideas beside hacking. Maybe this delay is unavoidable in vanilla XPE.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions anyway; a few more straws to clutch at are always welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could log in to the account you want to remote into via the physical machine and then lock the machine (or use "Fast User Switching" if you want to log in to a different account before remoting in).

If the account is already logged in remote desktop connections are pretty quick.

I generally never shut down my work computer or log off of it because of this (I do lock it).

I believe one `csrss.exe` and `winlogon.exe` is going to exist for each logged on account on the system.  I do know that Windows wants to load your profile before it gives you a useable desktop, and if you are in a domain environment this includes loading your NTUSER.DAT registry hive possibly from a network share, applying GPO policies, and logon scripts.

Comment: The host machine is an embedded device which is relatively frequently rebooted. It always logs onto the same account on startup and the account never locks. The host is on a static IP address and even with a direct link and no domain controller etc. we still see the delay.

Comment: An idea: does your `mstsc` have in the "Local devices and resources" the printers enabled.  Clipboard and audio may have an effect.  You could try disabling the print spooler on the embedded device and see if that improves speed.  Even if you have no printers it still may have an effect to disable it.

Comment: I've tried disabling all sharing on the client connecting in but that had no noticeable affect. Audio is not forwarded. I've just tried disabling print spooling and that made no difference either.